# PNG strip image to animated photo file?

Tags: convert, image-processing, gif

I'm interested in turning an image strip into a **high quality** GIF or APNG file.

The image I particularly want to convert is a gradient image with dimensions 1530x1 made up of raw hexadecimal color codes.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing you want a 1px by 1px animation with each color in sequence?

It's pretty simple.
First use imagemagick to slice the image in individual frames. In this case - 1by1 images.

```
convert line.png -crop 1x1 +repage pixel_%04d.gif
```

Then with the same tool create animation from all the generated images:

```
convert -loop 0 -delay 2 ./pix* anim.gif
```

Adjust delay parameter to change animation speed (in 1/100 of second).

Here's your pixel: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NVA4T.gif

Resized:

[image: resized animation]